# Is there a way to detect how many digits were entered in a hex literal in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation, rgb

Here's the reason I ask:

```
uint32_t Color::hex(uint32_t a_hex, bool a_readAlphaBits /*= false*/) {
    A = (a_readAlphaBits ? ((a_hex >> 24) & 0xFF) / 255.0f : 1.0f);
    R = (((a_hex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f);
    G = (((a_hex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f);
    B = (((a_hex)& 0xFF) / 255.0f);
    return hex();
}
```

0xFF0000 represents pure red when read as RGB, but when read as RGBA it would be 0x00FF0000 which means the alpha bits are completely transparent.

Because I'd like to let the user enter RGB **or** RGBA and I know of no way to distinguish between 0x00000000 and 0x000000 at compile or run time automatically, I have to add a "readAlphaBits" flag which if set to true will read the extra bits, otherwise default to 1.0f.

Ideally I would like this to be automatically detected.  Does anyone know of a way to determine how the literal was written?

I have an idea that involves differentiating based on a macro that goes

```
#define C_HEX(x) 0xFF##x
```

So that if someone enters C_HEX(000000) or C_HEX(00000000) it would be prefixed in such a way that at six digits the fully qualified value would be 32 bits, and at eight digits it would be 40.  I haven't tried this, but even if it works to distinguish the call at compile time I would prefer not to do something like that, I think a flag might be better in that case anyway.  If a user forgets to enter that macro it would kinda be lame even if I can detect it missing based on the memory layout of the value supplied.

But I can't think of much else in terms of detection.

Halp!

EDIT:

The ideal calling code would look like this (I have a similar hex based constructor for Color):

- Color(0xFF0000); //red rgba with alpha being 1.0
- Color(0x88FF0000); //red rgba with alpha being .533333333

Comment: Consider using C++11 user-defined literals

Comment: That sounds scary... Why not have classes instantiated like `rgb(FF0000)` and `rgba(00FF0000)` that encode the types of literal

Comment: #define len(x) sizeof(#x)

Comment: User-defined literals can do it, but then you have to parse the hex. Much easier just to define `00` to mean opaque and put alpha in the high-order bits.

Comment: @Brian Interesting idea.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: @NiklasB. I considered that, but my Color class is RGBA *always* so it isn't as scary as it seems.  It's just that I would like the user to be able to supply an RGB value with A implicitly set to 1.0, this is a reasonable default.

Comment: @M2tM: Okay, so then why not have two *functions* `rgb` and `rgba`, that both return a `Color`? Is it too much to ask of a programmer to decide whether to add that one letter or not?

Comment: @DaleWilson Wow that is hacky

Comment: @NiklasB. Also considered that, but it's pretty explicit in the value supplied, and I've got a thing for elegance.  What I have right now may as well be two functions, but I'd like not to have that.

Comment: @M2tM We obviously have different opinions about elegance ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. That's fair.  I'm just saying I've asked a simple question.  I'm not asking a style question, this is technical.  I'm more interested in Potatoswatter's approach to answering than the "why would you want to do that" type of dismissal I see that is all too common on tech sites.

Comment: How about just doing `(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b, uint8_t a = 0xFF)`? This way they can also use decimal if they want to.

Comment: @M2tM: Fair enough. I think these suggestions have their place, because a lot of users try to solve problems that are actually no problems at all, just the result of their wrong approaches. It makes sense to push them into the direction of more pragmatic solutions.

Comment: @user2802841 I certainly do have those methods too.

Comment: @Danra I'm not too worried about someone entering information here in a funny way.  These methods are primarily useful for copy/pasting values from other apps like photoshop, or website html color codes.  If you want a safer interface I have R, G, B, A calling syntax too.  The only purpose of this is convenience.  If you want to write 0xDEADBEE go for it.  It'll show up as the wrong color, and if it isn't different enough from what's expected, it's not going to ruin the world. This is about calling convenience.

Comment: Do you really have any cases where someone wants to produce a fully transparent pixel with a color? If not then there's only one ambiguous input, `0`. And that could be covered by a default with alpha=0.0, so that explicitly setting it to `0` would be alpha=1.0.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was considering this, it may be the cleanest option.  I don't like the inability to do 00 for alpha in this method, but I would kind of prefer that to the current flag I have.  I don't have any more than an emotional distaste for this.  It's a reasonable suggestion, and better than what I have.

Comment: Why not just reading it as a string and parsing it? It is only executed on user input, so speed is not a factor.

Comment: @vsz Not a bad suggestion.  Not ideal, but better than some alternatives.

Comment: @M2tM I wrote it as an answer for the sake of possible future visitors,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions, neither of which is perfect.

First is to modify your original function so that an alpha value of `00` results in the default alpha of 1.0:

```
uint32_t Color::hex(uint32_t a_hex, bool a_readAlphaBits = false) {
    A = a_readAlphaBits || (a_hex & 0xff000000) ? ((a_hex >> 24) & 0xFF) / 255.0f : 1.0f;
    R = ((a_hex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
    G = ((a_hex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
    B = ((a_hex)& 0xFF) / 255.0f;
    return hex();
}
```

This leaves you with having to specify the extra parameter if you want any fully transparent color.

Now you can use a macro to specify *both* parameters, going by the number of digits.

```
#define C_HEX(x) 0x##x, (sizeof(#x)>7)
```

Comment: Accepting this because I think the suggestion is pretty good to do the a_readAlphaBits || alpha bits are not zero.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of using the preprocessor. Couldn't you also just concatenate `FF` onto the beginning? Unsigned integer modulo arithmetic will just remove it if the number is already 8 digits long. I suppose although it's valid C/C++, it would result in a warning that you wouldn't want to disable.

Answer (score 2):

Without having to rely on C++11 or newer, you can just read it as a string, and parse it.
It is of course a little slower than the alternatives, but as it only has to be evaluated on user input, speed is not a factor here. An advantage would be that it's easier to understand and maintain than using macros and bit shifts.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 you can use a literal template operator:

```
template< char ... c >
rgba_type operator "" _rgb ();
```

or a raw literal operator:

```
rgba_type operator "" _rgb ( char * token, std::size_t len );
```

But then you have to take the trouble of parsing the hexadecimal digits, and if you want this to happen at compile time (as opposed to runtime) it all has to be `constexpr`. This is less painful in the upcoming C++14, but touching hex digits at all is probably overkill.

It would be much more reasonable to let the user specify `ARGB` with zero being opaque so they can omit the high-order bits. If that is the wrong format for your application, you can let a much simpler user-defined literal translate it for you:

```
constexpr rgba_type operator "" _rgb ( unsigned long long argb_opaque )
    { return ( ~ argb_opaque >> 24 ) & 0x000000FF
              | ( argb_opaque << 8 ) & 0xFFFFFF00; ) }
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, setting 0 as opaque by default was my first thought, but part of the problem is that is not a very standard method of identifying a color.  Part of my reason behind supporting RGB+RGBA hex values is the ability to copy/paste from other applications.  I lose that when I flip around the alpha bits (even if it isn't common to have alpha in a color code).  Can you elaborate on how constexpr might help here, and how rgba_type would be used in the final calling syntax?

Comment: I don't understand those last two questions.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the final Color(HEXVALUEWITHYOURSUGGESTION_FOR_RGB_AND_RGBA_ON_SEPARATE_LINES) would look like?  And can you elaborate on how touching hex digits might work, or where I could read further on that approach?  You hint at it, but do not go into detail. :3

Comment: @M2tM I said it would be painful. You're on your own. And it would look like `0xRRGGBBAA_color`, not a like a function call. (Actually the `x` is optional; it's part of what you would need to parse.)